# Debug Assertion Failed OpenCv is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am new to Programming using Visual Studio and openCv. I wrote a simple program to display the red channel of an image, but every time i run the code it throws "DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED" error.

```
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:/Users/siddartha/Pictures/sample.jpg");
    if (!image.data) {
        cout << "Cannot load image";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        if (image.channels() >= 3) {
            vector<Mat> rgb;
            split(image, rgb);
            namedWindow("r");
            imshow("r", rgb[0]);

        }
    }
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...sual Studio 2015\Projects\sampleOpenCV\Debug\sampleOpenCV.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 892

Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)
```

[image: Error Window]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get \_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) and/or is\_block\_type\_valid(header->\_block\_use) assertions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418624/why-do-i-get-crtisvalidheappointerblock-and-or-is-block-type-validheader-b)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure that the image has been loaded correctly?

I would think that it hasn't been loaded correctly and because of that the vector `rgb` is empty and, in turn, the element `rgb[0]` doesn't exist which triggers the exception ...

A couple of things I noted:

1. Use slashes (`/`) for include-statements not backslashes (`\`), i.e.

   ```
   #include <opencv2\core.hpp> // Bad!
   #include <opencv2/core.hpp> // Good!
   ```
2. In your check

   ```
   if (!image.data) { ... }
   ```

   **do not** assume that `image.data` is set to `NULL` or `nullptr` for empty   images. Instead check

   ```
   if (!image.empty()) { ... }
   ```
3. Make sure that calls to `cv::imshow(...)` are followed by a call to `cv::waitKey( /* delay in ms or 0 to wait for user input */ )`, cf. the note in the [OpenCV reference](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563).
4. `while (1);` -- is that intentional? What you want is probably `cv::waitKey( 0 )` (see 3.).

**UPDATE:**

5. Make sure the vector `rgb` has been initialized to the number of channels, i.e.

   ```
   vector<Mat> rgb(image.channels());
   split(image, rgb);
   // ...
   ```

**UPDATE 2:**

> Can you tell me what exactly the error meant ?

Three things:

1. The default constructor of `std::vector<T>` creates an *empty* vector.
2. Apparently, `cv::split()` expects the caller, i.e. *you*, to allocate data for the output. If you fail to do so, it's likely provoke a [segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault).
3. For debug builds some compilers add padding or safety memory around objects in memory which is never to be touched. If this padding memory is altered at runtime, the program "knows" that something bad happened and throws an exception like the one you saw.

Comment: I did all the corrections you stated. but now it shows DEBUG Assertion Failure when i press a key in the end to exit.

Comment: updating the rgb worked for me. Can you tell me what exactly the error meant ?

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

it is compiling just fine for me. I am on visual-studio-2013.

here you have a case similar to yours, maybe it will help:
[debug-assertion-failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102123/debug-assertion-failed-expression-block-type-is-valid)